# Connecting a Docker container to a network interface / device instead of an IP address

Tags: udp, docker, broadcast, raw-sockets

After careful research, testing, and fiddling, I've only been able to find away to connect a Docker container to a given interface by forwarding from an IP/port. This can be accomplished by adding `-p Host-IP:Host-Port:Container-Port` to a `docker run` command.

I have an app that listens for UDP broadcasts (255.255.255.255), and have been unable to configure forwarding in such a way that my container will receive those broadcasts without forwarding all network traffic on the port I care about (no matter through which interface it comes in), ie: `-p Host-Port:Container-Port`.

It's possible to configure the container with `--net=host` and just write my code to bind to a given interface, which I've done and tested, but that still goes against the main idea of a container. The goal is to have multiple containers of the same app listening on different network interfaces (as in devices, not addresses).

Any ideas on how I could do this?

**EDIT #1**: After thinking about this some more, it may be possible that setting up the bridge over the required interface is enough, but I don't trust the OS to send the broadcast packets over it. Stay tuned as I perform more tests.

**EDIT #2**: Packets are sent over a bridge just fine. However, the bridge is configured as the Docker default bridge. I haven't been able to figure out how to run containers on different bridges. Saw some notes that point towards setting the network to `--net=none` and configuring it yourself through lxc container settings.

Comment: why is the docker bridge not good enough ?

Comment: Haven't been able to configure the docker bridge in a way where I can specify which network interface to attach to. Which means that I can't have separate containers per network interface.

Comment: can you post your solution? I need something similar to run a DHCP instance inside of a docker container

Answer (score -2):

By default docker run command publishes ports for tcp.
Try to specify use of udp:

`docker run -p Host-Port:Container-Port`**/udb** ...

Comment: The issue is not forwarding ports, it's forwarding data from a specific interface.

Comment: What interface do you want to forward?

Comment: I'm using the word "interface" in this case to denote a network device.

If I have a system that's dual homed and I only want to provide a service on one of the networks, I haven't found a way to do that. Forwarding data from a particular IP isn't sufficient in the case that I'm using broadcast or multicast packets.