# Wildfly/Jboss-v10 is not working in cluster mode with docker swarm

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have my web based java application working in `wildfly/jboss version 10`.I am using docker(`1.13.1-cs2`) to deploy my application.Now as per some HA(`High availability`) scenario I want my application to work in cluster mode.So I changes my wildfly configuration to cluster mode inside my `standalone-full-ha.xml`.After this changes everything works perfect only if I use default docker network and start container with `docker bridge network`. But As per my requirement I want this whole container/my application to work as a service by `docker swarm`.But if I start put this as a service than wildfly/jboss is not be able to start in cluster mode and throwing error like this :

```
21:01:27,885 ERROR (TransferQueueBundler,ee,WEB-APP-NODE) JGRP000029: WEB-APP-NODE: failed sending message to cluster (38 bytes): java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted, headers: NAKACK2: [HIGHEST_SEQNO, seqno=2631], TP: [cluster_name=ee]
21:01:28,826 ERROR (TransferQueueBundler,ee,WEB-APP-NODE) JGRP000029: WEB-APP-NODE: failed sending message to cluster (4166 bytes): java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted, headers: FORK: ee:activemq-cluster, NAKACK2: [MSG, seqno=2632], TP: [cluster_name=ee]
21:01:29,886 ERROR (TransferQueueBundler,ee,WEB-APP-NODE) JGRP000029: WEB-APP-NODE: failed sending message to cluster (38 bytes): java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted, headers: NAKACK2: [HIGHEST_SEQNO, seqno=2632], TP: [cluster_name=ee]
21:01:30,826 ERROR (TransferQueueBundler,ee,WEB-APP-NODE) JGRP000029: WEB-APP-NODE: failed sending message to cluster (4166 bytes): java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted, headers: FORK: ee:activemq-cluster, NAKACK2: [MSG, seqno=2633], TP: [cluster_name=ee]
```

**Note:** I am using default `swarm ingress network` for port expose and communication.

As per my troubleshooting this issue is related to multicast address used by `wildfly/jboss version 10` creating the issue.
I have also tried these steps [multicast address in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214608/docker-receiving-multicast-traffic)

But it is still not help in my case.Can anyone help me in this ?it is appreciated very much!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The overlay network from Docker Swarm does currently not support IP multicast.

You can either fallback to TCP based unicast for your cluster. But that leaves the challenge to know the IP addresses of all other containers in the service.

Another way is to create a `macvlan` based network which supports unicast. Tutorial: http://collabnix.com/docker-17-06-swarm-mode-now-with-macvlan-support/
With that variant I have the problem that as soon as you connect such a network to a container ingress (routing mesh) and access to the ouside world via docker_gwbridge stops working (details: [Docker Swarm container with MACVLAN network gets wrong gateway - no internet access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511409))